# Appium tap wihout need for element?

Tags: android, python, appium

I have following code to tap on center of screen. I dont want tap on any element. Just on center to dismiss some open panel. How do I do that?

```
 touch = TouchAction()
 dimension = driver.get_window_size()
 touch.tap(element=None, x=int(dimension['width']/2),y=int(dimension['height']/2)).perform()
```

Above code produces this error

```
self = <appium.webdriver.common.touch_action.TouchAction object at 0x7f6aa32a2810>

    def perform(self):
        """Perform the action by sending the commands to the server to be operated upon
            """
        params = {'actions': self._actions}
>       self._driver.execute(Command.TOUCH_ACTION, params)
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

#### Solution

In the above code the driver is missing as parameter when initializing TouchAction()
So all I needed to do was

```
touch = TouchAction(driver)
```

and code worked after....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TouchAction, example is on python client github page

```
el = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('Animation')
action = TouchAction(self.driver)
action.tap(el).perform()
el = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('Bouncing Balls')
self.assertIsNotNone(el)
```

You can also use coordinates (Java example)

```
new TouchAction(driver).press(802, 1770).release().perform();
```

I hope it'll help You ;)